# Drop Default Clustered Index Without Knowing it's Name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

I wrote a script that creates some tables (it previously drops them if they exist) and then tries to create two indexes on each table.

The first index uses the Primary Key column to create a non-clustered index, and the second uses another column to create the clustered indexed. This is because the primary key column is a GUID instead of an int.

How can I drop the default index if I don't know it's name? or how can I specify a name for the primary key column index so I can drop it? Or better yet, how can I specify the 2 index i need right in the Create Table statement?

Comment: The Primary Key is created with: `[GID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,` I'm not setting it to be clustered. Also the index name is something like `PK__[Table]__C51F0F3E60620756`.

Comment: If you're **NOT EXPLICITLY** telling the PK to be **NONCLUSTERED** - then it's clustered.

Comment: So try to use: `[GID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY **NONCLUSTERED** `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.indexes
```

However, I'm not understanding where in your process you actually have to drop an index.

You said you are creating some tables and then creating two indexes on each table.

If you are DROPping existing tables at the beginning, any indexes are automatically dropped.

There is no such thing as a default index.

Tables can either be heaps or clustered indexes.  If you drop the clustered index, the table will be converted to a heap and any non-clustered indexes will have to be updated to point to the data in the unordered heap.

You can create like this all at once:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl
(
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1) CONSTRAINT UK_ID UNIQUE CLUSTERED,
    SomeUUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_SomeUUID PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
)
```

Here's a SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d759e/12

Comment: When i create the table a clusterd intex is created by default on the primary key, what I need is a way to have the clustered index in another column, and use the primary column as non-clustered index.

Comment: @PedroC88 You can specify the PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED during creation.

Comment: @PedroC88 I added a SQLFiddle

Answer (score 3):

You can define the two indices right after you create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable ( ...... )
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (YourGuidColumn)
                                      ****************
                  this is crucial ! Otherwise, your PK will be clustered!


CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX01_YourTable ON dbo.YourTable(YourOtherColumn)

or even better:  
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX01_YourTable ON dbo.YourTable(YourOtherColumn)
```

That should create a **non-clustered primary key** and a separate (preferably unique) **clustered index** on a separate column.

Comment: I have a script much similar to that but it gives me an error because I'm trying to create a clustered index when the table already has one.

Comment: @PedroC88: in that case, you're **most likely** not explicitly specifying the `NONCLUSTERED` in the creation of the primary key; if you omit that, then the primary key will be created **as a clustered index**.